# How to format a date with a time value?

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

I think I got a rather simple problem at hand but I've been rather perplexed by it. I'm rather familiar with dates so far and converting them into 'Long' integers. However, I had to add a time value this particular instance to reflect a situation for the 'delivery time' in addition to the 'delivery date'. I understand that excel-vba provides functions for dates and times separately. I'm wondering how do I reflect a date and a date, say 10/06/2015, 7pm or 1900hrs (forgive me for the non-american format) into a single integer that I can work with. Something like, e.g:

```
dim y as date
y = "10/06/2015"
dbldate = Clng(y)
```

but with an additional component of time of 7pm. Sorry for being rather verbose with my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both the worksheet and VBA, *time* is just the fractional part of a floating point value.  So:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim db As Double, dt As Date
    db = 12345.67
    dt = CDate(db)
    MsgBox dt
End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

and to convert *Date/Time* as a **string** to a floating point value:

```
Sub Backwards()
    Dim st As String, db As Double
    st = "12/25/2014 7:00PM"
    db = DateValue(st) + TimeValue(st)
    MsgBox db
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know timevalue could be utitlized in this fashion

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dt as Date
Dim dbl as Double

'Add 19 hours to the date for 7pm
dt = DateAdd("h", 19, y)

'Convert it to a double to hold date (integer) and time (decimal) components
dbl = CDbl(dt)

'dbl will = 42165.7916666667
```

Comment: interesting approach, I'll keep that in mind the next time